# django make a one-to-many relationship contain a True value for only one object instance, others should revert to False on this field

Tags: django

I have the following django model:

```
from django.db import models
from django.db.models import Q, UniqueConstraint
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
import random


class ReferralCode(models.Model):
    code_str = models.CharField(max_length=64,
                                primary_key=True,
                                default="".join(
                                    [chr(random.randrange(48, 123))
                                     for y in range(64)]))
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            UniqueConstraint(
                fields=["user", "active"],
                condition=Q(active=True),
                name="unique_active_code_for_user",
            )
        ]
```

On creation of a ReferralCode with active=True I want others to revert to False, how do I do that? Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you want to when user creates a new **Referral code** then automatically older becomes **`active = False`** then you can achieve those things using overriding **`save()`** method.

```py
class ReferralCode(models.Model):
    code_str = models.CharField(
        max_length=64,
        primary_key=True,
        default="".join([chr(random.randrange(48, 123)) for _ in range(64)]),
    )
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # If this referral code is being marked as active,
        # deactivate all other codes for the same user
        if self.active:
            ReferralCode.objects.filter(user=self.user, active=True).exclude(
                pk=self.pk
            ).update(active=False)
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```